# Use Places API (Discover/Here) with Address instead of Lat/Long

Tags: here-api

I currently have a POC working that retrieves places information using the Places HERE api by passing Lat and Long values. Our addresses are being converted to lat and long before the api is called and we fear we might be losing precision in the process. Instead of feeding the API the coordinates, is there a way to send the actual address and get the address information back? Business name, type, etc?

res = requests.get('https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/here?app_id=<>&app_code=<>&at='+str(lat)+','+str(long))

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in the API docs (https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/resource-search.html) the answer is no. You can see more detail here as well: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/location-contexts.html. Is there a particular example of where you think geocoding is returning bad results?

Answer (score 0):

Use Geocoder API to get coordinates for address and then use these coordinates to make a request to Places API.